# "Pretty" as an adverb

Tags: idioms, dialects, formality

How correct/common/proper is "pretty" as an adverb? It is hard for me to see, since it's my native dialect, but I say "pretty often" pretty often, and "fairly often" fairly rarely. Does "pretty" mark me as informal or uneducated or rustic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOAD reports that *pretty* used as adverb is informal, and it means *to a moderately high degree, fairly*: *he looked pretty fit for his age*.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how 'pretty' is an adverb in "he looked pretty fit for his age"?  Doesn't 'pretty' modify 'fit' in this example, and isn't 'fit' a noun?

Comment: _fit_ is also an adjective; in the sentence I reported, it is an adjective, similarly to _nice_ in _she looks nice_.

Answer (score 5):

It's informal, but correct. [The Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pretty_1) lists an adverb form.

Comment: It is very general, vague, and probably overused, so the use of "pretty" doesn't really ever come off as sophisticated in speech or writing.  But like Neil Fein says, it is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's [pretty common](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretty#Usage_notes).