# What is the origin of "pretty" as slang for "somewhat"?

Tags: etymology, slang

We now often hear phrases like:

> That's pretty interesting.

The word "pretty" here is used to say "somewhat," "considerably/rather," or something along those lines (if a little stronger).

However, this definition doesn't appear in any dictionary I've searched.

What is the earliest known use of this form? More generally, how did this use of "pretty" come about?

Comment: It goes back a long way. OED's first citation is **1565**   *T. Cooper Thesaurus,   Audaculus, **a pretie hardie felow**: vsed in derision.*

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Pretty" as an adverb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496/pretty-as-an-adverb)

Comment: @Fumble This isn't a duplicate, because I'm asking about the origin, not the usage. Interesting point, however. Thanks!

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate. It's not my problem if the original question doesn't happen to have any answers specifically addressing the *origin* issue. But given we're talking about something that happened around 500 years ago, I'm not sure how likely it is that anyone will be able to explain exactly how the original ***pretty** = cunning, crafty. Subsequently: clever, skilful, able* shifted across to *a considerable extent; fairly, moderately; rather, quite. In later use also: very.*

Comment: @Fumble That doesn't mean it should be closed as a question it's not a duplicate of.

Comment: You're simply repeating your position, which I disagree with. In case it wasn't obvious from my previous (explanatory) comment, I personally do not consider *"What's the origin of [word]?"* to be sufficiently distinct from *"How correct/common/proper is [word]?"* as to merit a separate question. Certainly not as a general principle, and not in this specific case.

Comment: The answers to the other question don't touch on the origins of adverbial _pretty_ at all... which is hardly surprising, given that the asker didn't inquire about origins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As FumbleFingers says, this is a pretty old use, going back to Early Modern English:

> **Pretty** (pri•ti) *adv.* Forms: see prec. [The adj. in adverbial use.]
>    **1.** To a considerable extent, considerably; in a fair or moderate degree, fairly, moderately, tolerably; [...]
>   **1598** FLORIO *Dict.* Ep. Ded. 3 Boccace is prettie hard, yet understood: Petrarche harder but explained.  —[*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdic07murruoft#page/1332/mode/2up)

(I offer this *OED 1* citation rather than the earlier one reproduced by FumbleFingers because I am not convinced that the use in the earlier citation is adverbial.)

*Pretty* has a complicated history, as you may see from the *OED 1* entry which immediately precedes the link above: from *cunning, artful* to *clever, skilful* to ‘a general epithet of admiration or appreciation... fine, pleasing, proper’, and so forth, leading to the main modern sense ‘having beauty without majesty or stateliness’; but the origin of this adverbial use clearly lies in *OED 1* sense 5 for the adjective:

> **5.** Considerable in number, quantity, or extent, as in *a pretty deal, while, way*, etc.; also *a pretty many* = a good many; ...

*OED 1* gives citations for this use dating from *c.* 1485 down to 1861, but marks it as ‘Now *arch.* or *dial.*’

I am surprised you did not find this in any dictionary; I found it in the first three online dictionaries I checked, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pretty?showCookiePolicy=true), [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pretty?q=pretty), and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretty). All three post definitions for the adverb after those for the adjective.

Comment: Is _cunning, artful to clever ..._ marked as obsolete in OED(1)? I still use that to mean _clever_ as in _you're pretty aren't you?_ meaning _you think that's bloody smart don't you?_. That's twice this week I've been caught being obsolete.

Comment: @Frank *OED 1* marks the narrow senses *cunning, artful, &c* as *obs.* or *arch.*, but not the "general epithet", for which it specifically notes (3.c.) *ironic* uses. I think you're right, and *pretty* is still used in the *clever, artful* senses: "He has a pretty sense of comedy and timing."

Comment: Is that use of *pretty* a US thing? I don't think I have ever heard it...

Comment: @JamesRandom It's not common; it's known in academic registers but somewhat literary and oldfashioned today. **I** use it; but it is likely I picked it up from 19th century British sources.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it has to do with French influence after the Norman conquest from the expression "près de" (near) since it means "close to" or "right up to"? I have NO evidence of this.  Does anyone?  This just came to mind.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. An answer with "NO evidence" is the antithesis of what we are looking for in a response.

Comment: As an intuitive thinker, I find this answer very impressive. It motivates me to research it further.

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes back much further, to the Latin 'pretiosus' meaning pricy, valuable, expensive  - hence its early adjectival use in the phrase 'a pretty penny'. Pretiosus comes from the Latin 'pretium' meaning a price. Smith's Latin Dictionary has pretiosus right back in Cicero in the first century BC, and points out that 'pretium' goes right back to a Sanscrit rooot.
Similarly the word 'dear' means both 'beloved' and 'expensive'. Possibly its meaning changed once the use of money became normalised, and this brought in the developed meaning
Please prove me wrong, someone! it would be good to know if the earliest Early English usages were in areas where the Romans were in control, for example.

Comment: But _pretty_ isn't etymologically related to _pretium_ at all. The borrowings (from French) of the descendants of _pretium_ and _pretiōsus_ are _price_ and _precious_, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the phrase "pretty please", I believe that the origin comes from a variation of the request : "I pray thee, please." "I pray thee "morphed into the single word: "prithee". Prithee is a very old contraction that was used in Shakespeare.  Thus "prithee please" then became "pretty please". This is a personal conjecture, but one that rings true.

Comment: Hello Sheldon Schorer! Welcome to EL&U please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).Thanks for taking the time to answer. Please add some references to back up your answer

Answer (score 1):

[John Kelly's **ODO article**](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2018/04/30/what-in-the-word-pretty-origin/) explains the semantic shifts. BTW, [Anatoly Liberman's doesn't.](https://blog.oup.com/2007/11/pretty/).

---

> ## What in the Word?! ‘Pretty’ is… not quite as pretty does
>
> That’s a *pretty* dress. I’m *pretty* sure I locked the car. Her new watch cost a *pretty* penny. We came to a *pretty* pass in our negotiations. How does this *pretty* manage to mean ‘attractive’, ‘considerably’, ‘expensive’, and ‘difficult’ all at once? It’s a tricky little word – literally so.
>
> Language, if there’s one thing we can say about it, is constantly changing. And not even the core meanings of some English’s most basic words are safe from language’s inexorable flux. Take *nice*. It meant ‘foolish’ 600 years ago, undergoing a type of [semantic change](https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/HE_Change_Semantic.htm#types) called [*amelioration*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amelioration). Or *silly*, which started out as ‘happy’ or ‘fortunate’, an example of semantic [*pejoration*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pejoration). *Handsome*, [as we explored in the inaugural post of this series](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2017/08/15/what-in-the-word-handsome/), began as ‘easy to handle’.
>
> *Pretty* joins this incredible group. If we time-travelled to an Anglo-Saxon village, wandered around its thatched huts, smithies, and rows of barley, and listened to folks speak, we wouldn’t recognize the word *pretty*. For one, in one of its Old English forms of *prættig*, it would have sounded very different, something like ‘prat-teeh’. For another, it meant ‘clever’ or ‘cunning’. Yes, *pretty* was originally a crafty word.
>
> ## A ‘trick’ up its sleeve
>
> The word [*pretty*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pretty) has its roots in *prat*, a word for ‘trick’ or ‘prank’, and features the common adjective suffix *-y*. The word *prat* is Germanic, with living cognates in the likes of the Dutch *prettig* (‘nice, pleasant’). It bears no relation to [*prattle*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prattle) or, alas, [*pratfall*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pratfall), whose *prat* is actually an old slang term for the buttocks.
>
> The ‘tricky’ *prat* really only survived in the Shetland dialect up until the mid-1900s or so – and in names. The surname [*Pratt*](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Pratt), like actor Chris Pratt, apparently originated as a byname for someone ‘full of wiles’. The proto-Pratt must have been the village tinkerer, always cooking up some scheme.
>
> Surnames are indeed noteworthy in the history of *pretty*. As the *Oxford English Dictionary* observes: ‘Between the end of the Old English period and the 15<sup>th</sup> cent. the word is only attested in surnames (e.g., Simone *Praty* (1301), Henry *Praty* (1304), Johannes *Pratyman* (1343), and Willelmus *Pritty* (1428))…’
>
> Mr Willelmus *Pritty*, for one, appears to reflect the modern pronunciation of the word. Pretty is also an example of another linguistic oddity, where the modern spelling and pronunciation reflect different pathways in the word’s (very complicated) form history.
>
> Why the gap? We can only speculate. The record only preserves what was written – and historically, what was deemed important to be written. We should remember that writing was a rare skill in the Middle Ages and permanent writing was done on expensive parchment, reserved for the loftier and [more formal subjects](http://web.ceu.hu/medstud/manual/MMM/frame1.html) of religion, law, finance, and poetry. *Pretty*, for whatever reason, didn’t make the cut, except for our friends Johannes and Willelmus, with their names scratched into feudal ledgers or the like.
>
> That all changed by the mid-1400s, when the *OED* finds evidence for a range of emerging senses of *pretty*. And there is a logic to its progression. Something ‘tricky’ can be seen as ‘clever’, and something ‘clever’ can <s>we</s> [typo] be well made, which is ‘pleasing’ to the eye. This ‘attractive’ *pretty* is attested of people, especially women and children, by 1440, in the same source that gives us the earliest record of *handsome* so far, the English-Latin bilingual dictionary *Promptorium Parvulorum*: ‘Praty, *elegans*, *formosus*, *elegantulus*, *formulosus*’, i.e., elegant or finely formed, with a suggestion of daintiness or delicacy.
>
> By at least 1475, *pretty* was characterizing things as exactly the opposite of small and intricate – as ‘considerable’ or ‘sizable’, e.g. a *pretty many* or, come the 1700s, a *pretty penny*. We see a similar jump in other ‘attractive’ or ‘worthwhile’ descriptors: a *fair* amount, a *good* many, a *handsome* sum.
>
> ## Talking *pretty*
>
> From here, *pretty* made its next jump, hopping grammatical categories from adjective to adverb. This development isn’t exactly a giant leap, though, as it’s a short step from ‘considerable’ to ‘to a considerable extent’, recorded in the latter half of the 16<sup>th</sup> century. *Very* undergoes a parallel evolution from an adjective for ‘true’ to an adverb for ‘to high degree’.
>
> What’s interesting, though, is how *pretty* became more widespread than its expected adverbial form, *prettily*, attested by 1450. It originally meant ‘skilfully’ and is now mainly, if infrequently, used for ‘politely’ or ‘charmingly’. What’s also interesting is the subtlety of the adverbial *pretty*. Think of it this way: How would you explain the differences among *good*, *pretty good* and *very good* to a non-native English speaker? It talks and sits pretty, *pretty*.
>
> The same goes for the adjectival *pretty*: How would you teach an English-language learner when to use *pretty* vs. *beautiful*? What connotations would you tell your student to mind? How about *who* we call *pretty*, a term, for better or worse, reserved for women just as *handsome* is for men (e.g. [*pretty boy*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pretty_boy))?
>
> *Pretty* also made the jump to noun, an ‘attractive thing’ (e.g., *my pretty*) or ‘a large amount of money’. Some golfers also called the fairway *a pretty* in the early 20<sup>th</sup> century. *Pretty*, too, inspired a verb, *prettify*, as early as 1661 and *pretty up* by 1863.
>
> *Pretty* didn’t completely shed all its original ‘subterfuge’ over the centuries, however. By the early 1500s, *pretty* came to describe something as ‘awkward, difficult, or unwelcome’, a sense which survives in phrases such as a *pretty mess*, a [*pretty pass*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/come_to_a_pretty_pass), or a [*pretty kettle of fish*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_pretty_(or_fine)_kettle_of_fish). And every now and again, US sports writers will call an athlete a *pretty player*, not referring to looks but skill, a sense of *pretty* lingering from the 15<sup>th</sup> century.
>
> ## Purty and pooty
>
> And what about, finally, *purty*? Is that just the ignorance of some bumpkin or the drawl of the cowboy? The *OED* finds *purty* in British writer Aphra Behn’s 1682 comedic play, *The City Heiress* – not exactly the backwoods or Wild West. This sound-switching of pretty’s ‘r’ and vowel has a name, [*metathesis*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metathesis), and gave us *bird* from its original *brid* and third from *thrid*.
>
> *Pooty* is another variant pronunciation of pretty founded in the 1820s – dropping the tricky ‘r’ altogether, something Old English occasionally did, as we can find *pæti* for *pretty* in the record. But let’s not worry our pretty little heads about the loss of ‘r’s in Old English consonant clusters, pretty please